# Getting Uncaught ReferenceError in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this function in javascript:

```
var summaryObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
var fieldsToConvertToFixedNumbers = ["total_wt_arr_slp", "total_wt_ivwap_slp"];

for(var i = 0; i < summaryObj.length; i++) {
    var obj = summaryObj[i];
    for(key in obj) {
        if(fieldsToConvertToFixedNumbers.indexOf(key) != -1) {
        obj[key] = Number(obj[key]).toFixed(2);
      }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Which line is showing this error?  What is `summaryObj`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat for(key in obj) is showing the error

Comment: `for (var key in obj)` or new ESNext stuff `for (let key in obj)`

Comment: could you provide the jsonStr? Otherwise we have no way of determing what is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your key isn't defined. You need to change:

```
for(key in obj) {
```

to

```
for(var key in obj) {
```

to define your key.

Comment: Oh yeah! I don't know it was working before without var also. :/

Comment: @Angad In less strict environments, it won't care, it'll let you use it undefined. However, nowadays, most modern browsers and a lot of environments and/or preprocessors will enforce more strict standards, hence getting this error now.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `key` before using it.

`for(var key in obj)`

I hope, it will solve your problem.